# joomla jdoc:include?

Tags: joomla

Im new to joomla and have been asked to edit part of a site currently in place by someone who is no longer accessible to ask questions.

There is text ii cant see within the edit html part of the template which i think is located maybe in
 `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" />` or `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="topmenu" />`

Where or how to i access the text that is in this jdoc include?  i dont get where it is?

Can someone help?

Comment: For future reference you might want to consider posting to http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ for Joomla questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to accomplish? Chances are, you shouldn't be editing any files at all, you should be using the admin to make changes.

To answer your question, the way Joomla works is to build each "page" of a website based on the main content area which is filled in by a component then fill in content around that in different module positions. The pieces of code you listed are used to display all of the modules in the associated position. Modules are assigned to a position based on the page you are on in the Module Manager.

The positions are often named either a) by their position relative to the main content or b) the content that is intended for that area of the template. However, as with the examples in your question, the "search" position can display any type of module in it, it does not have to be a search box.

Comment: i think there is text within that area i need to edit.  where and how i can i edit the text thats in that area?

Comment: its definetly in <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" /> because if i change name=search to name=searchh the text i want to edit disappears as well as the search box

Comment: In the admin, you can go to the Module Manager, then look at what modules are published on the "search" position. Those modules will control everything that displays in that position.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you've to edit the text in the part where `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" />` is located. It means, It contains a module whose position is 'search'. 
Go to `module manager` of admin section, now click on the module with positioned 'search'. There you'll see the module parameters and edit it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder, go to the `modules` folder (in your case it is `search module` and `menu module`). You will find these two folders `mod_search and mod_menu`.
 Open `tmpl/default.php` file. Here you get the html of these module. If there is no effect by changing the html. Then it is case of overriding. You have to go to your default template for frontend. in the template folder there is html folder, here you can find `mod_search and mod_menu` if the case of overriding. `Default.php` file is having html. 
Exact path for overrider: `template/{yourtemplate}/html/mod_search/default.php`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is to options:
1. Look at administrator part, **"exntensions"->"module manager"** and set up filters to view modules at **positions: "serach"** and go through this module.
If text is not in this modules:
2. Go to **templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/modules.php** and see if this text is hard coded in this file.
Also you can look through another **files/folders in templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/** it may be hard coded somewhere else there.
Or it may be hardcoded by the worst way in your search module.

Answer (score 0):

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" />` means a template is loading a search module in that location. If you want to edit the searchmodule, you need not edit the template index.php file itself. You can just log into the backend and look up the search module there from extensions ->module manager.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no content text at all in any of the files.
All the text should be in the database.
It should be in one of the content articles accessible through the admin panel.

Of course, sometimes people do odd things and if you can't ask the previous developer you can't rule that out completely, but (hopefully) the text won't be anywhere else.

As mentioned by others, it will be a module displaying the text, in the admin panel select Extensions -> Modules and probably you can filter on "position = topmenu".

Is the text actually in a menu (as the position names might suggest)?
If so, go to the menu manager to find the menu item to change.  Otherwise, to find the text you're talking about, but even so the text may still be in an article, which you find in the admin panel by selecting "Content".

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at what is called a "chrome" 
In your template (/wwwroot/templates/yourtemplate/html/modules.php)
This file controls how your template renders your modules.
As others have said the "search" is the name of the module position.

Perhaps you could be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve?